# Accordion change through navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, jquery-ui-accordion

I want to change the accordion based on clicking a link .It is working fine.The demo is shown in the following link
http://jsfiddle.net/kufi/qp5Mg/

Now,I want to change the color of link  that clicked(here from red to green).If I click a link it is changing from red to green .If i Click second link the first link remains in green only,It should be changed to red.

Answer (score 0):

refer below link for this,

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

```
               OR
```

http://chandreshmaheshwari.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/accordian-menu/

Thanks.